# Renomear parte dos nomes dos parâmetros de uma procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Tenho algumas procedures em que os nomes de parâmetros iniciar com: **"p_"**. É possível alterar de uma forma única e via código todos os nomes de todas as procedures que iniciam com essa abreviação por: **"abc_"** por exemplo?

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%' PROCEDURE `postSac`(
        IN p_nome VARCHAR(255),
        IN p_telefone VARCHAR(15),
        IN p_email VARCHAR(100),
        IN p_cidade VARCHAR(100),
        IN p_estado VARCHAR(2),
        IN p_assunto VARCHAR(255),
        IN p_mensagem LONGTEXT
    )
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN
         SHOW WARNINGS;
         #SELECT 0 AS retorno;
         ROLLBACK;
      END;
   START TRANSACTION;

   INSERT INTO sac (nome, telefone, email, cidade, estado, assunto, mensagem) VALUES (p_nome, p_telefone, p_email, p_cidade, p_estado, p_assunto, p_mensagem);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente acabei descobrindo que isso não é possível:

> Esta declaração pode ser usada para alterar as características de um
>   procedimento armazenado. Mais de uma alteração pode ser especificada
>   em uma ALTER PROCEDUREdeclaração. No entanto, você não pode alterar os
>   parâmetros ou o corpo de um procedimento armazenado usando esta
>   declaração; Para fazer essas mudanças, você deve soltar e recriar o
>   procedimento usando DROP PROCEDUREe CREATE PROCEDURE.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-procedure.html